# Similarity measure for point clouds

Tags: python, 3d, computer-vision, geometry, similarity

I am currently doing a project related to using point cloud.
My ultimate goal is that using the point cloud, I want to find an another similar point cloud.
I saw some posts about using chamfer distance or cosine similarity. Could you please recommend me some clever ways of measuring similarities between two point clouds?
Thank you

Comment: Please, define "similarity" of two point-clouds.

Comment: I meant the similarity as feature-wise not pixelwise or pointwise(?) if you understand what I mean.
Hence, my goal is to match two point clouds which have similar features

Comment: Too wide. I can think of many features: Max/min positions; Max/min distances between points; Density; Homogeneity; Triangulation (vertices relations); Contour shape; etc etc

Comment: Scale the points in the point cloud to the same scale and then snap them to a grid. IE: Min X/Y/Z is 0. Max X/Y/Z is K for some K (K=1 would work, but you could just use (abs(max X) + abs(min X), for math purpose, one might define K as actually 2^(k)). Convert the X/Y/Z values to integers, effectively snapping the point cloud to a K x K grid.  This makes the two point clouds comparable.What you do after words depends. Check for similarity by calculating what value of K is needed before the dissimilarity (not matching / total) to exceeds X percent.  Can use math need to limit the need to split.